# Export Animation from Maya to Unity with Segment Scale Compensate

Tags: unity, animation, maya, rigging, export

Currently, we are trying to export an animation from Maya which has some joint scale changes during the animation. As you may have encountered before Maya is using Segment Scale Compensate, however, we have already created the animation and don't want to change the working process on Maya.

Is there any way that we can export the animation correctly for Unity? Did anyone encounter this problem?

Thank you

Comment: You may get better answers if you can explain what Segment Scale Compensate is doing and what unwanted symptoms you're seeing in Unity after import. That way even users who don't have first hand experience with this specific workflow, but know how to solve analogous problems whose solutions also apply here, can give you the benefit of that insight.